# Camel Splitter Aggregator requires dummy statement

Tags: apache-camel

When using split/aggregator in camel (2.14) the following throws an exception:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("timer://foo?repeatCount=1")
    .bean(someBean)
    .split(body(), new MyAgg())  
    .end()
    .bean(printBean);
} 

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> Split[{body} -> []] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[timer://foo?repeatCount=1]] -> [Bean[org... because of Definition has no children on Split[{body} -> []]
```

Whereas the following works fine:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("timer://foo?repeatCount=1")
        .bean(someBean)
        .split(body(), new MyAgg())  
        .log("blah blah")
        .end()
        .bean(printBean);
}
```

someBean sets a List of String in the exchange. printBean prints out the exchange at the end. MyAgg appends the string from exchanges.

The log statement in the second option seems redundant. Is there an option to make the first option work?

Comment: It looks like overengineering. Why do you split and aggregates strings again? If MyAgg changes somehow the format, just merge the functionality of someBean and MyAgg and remove splitter at all

Comment: @Sergey this is a made up example. I am working on a problem that requires splitter/aggregation. I realized that I need to put a statement between split() and end() to make the aggregation work. So I made up an small example to make this point.

Comment: I see. Then you should not be worry about empty splitter body. In real life situation you will always have a splitter body (some to(), process(), etc). Otherwise it would not be necessary to use a splitter at all

Comment: Yes its required for splitter to have 1 or more outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something with split message. Just Add an empty processor if you don't want to do anything with split message.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("timer://foo?repeatCount=1")
    .bean(someBean)
    .split(body(), new MyAgg())
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        }
    })
    .end()
    .bean(printBean);
}
```